# Access Google Chrome Bookmarks with Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I've searched around, there don't seem to be any built in shortcuts. Is there a way to customize shortcuts with an extension or an extension that is built specifically for accessing bookmarks?

EDIT:
I want to be able to press a configuration of buttons on my keyboard, not my mouse, to select bookmarks. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd></s>

Opens the Bookmark manager.
Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> or the arrow keys to move around and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the bookmark

Chrome has moved on to in-tab based bookmark manager, so the above step no longer works. To open Bookmarks, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to move focus to the Omnibox, type in `chrome://bookmarks` to access the bookmarks page. From there you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> or the arrow keys to move around and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the bookmark

Comment: this is close, but shift+alt+t doesn't put the focus on the bookmarks toolbar, only the browser toolbar. and navigation from the browser toolbar to the bookmarks is impossible with the arrow keys

Comment: @nrhine - yes. Opening the Bookmark manager should be fine right?

Comment: I edited the question -  I want to be able to open the bookmarks with solely my keyboard. None of these options allow that.

Comment: nrhine - You can still use solely your Keyboard. Ctrl+Shift+B opens the bookmarks manager. Use Tab/arrow keys to move around and Enter to open the bookmark

Comment: ah yes. Hit tab twice after ctrl+shift+b and then use arrow keys. Thanks

Comment: This appears to no longer work for recent versions of chrome.

Comment: @Zoredache thanks for letting me know, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 16):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> opens the Bookmarks Bar.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> focuses it.

From there you can use Tab or arrow keys to select the link you want.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>, arrow keys, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Detailed Explanation**
Press {F6} once to focus on the location bar.
Press {F6} again to focus on the bookmarks bar.
Then use {Arrow} keys and {Enter}.

Comment: F6 - indeed switches focus from omnibar to bookmarks bar and other bars.

Answer (score 6):

On a Mac:

1. System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Plus button
3. Application = Google Chrome, Menu Title = [bookmark title as it appears in the Bookmarks menu], Keyboard Shortcut = [shortcut]

Or on any OS:

1. Chrome > Preferences > Manage Search Engines
2. Add a new "search engine" with the URL to bookmark and a keyword.
3. To open the bookmark type Command-L, keyword, Enter.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

It's even better because you have **more options**. You can navigate with the keyboard, or use the search functionality for your bookmarks.

Comment: Correct solution as of now.

Answer (score -1):

I've been wondering this myself.  I haven't found anything which actually solves this, but you can hack it a bit with this extension: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf

It unfortunately seems to have some trouble with command-key shortcuts.  But that could just be on my system.

Essentially, it lets you create static events for keystrokes.  Among others, it can open a webpage (== bookmark) or run javascript (== bookmarklet).  Maybe they'll add in bookmark-launching by number eventually, but it's not in there now.