# Google Chrome - Attach a Key Binding to a Bookmark

Tags: mac, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, bookmarks

Is there a way to create a key command / key binding / whatever you want to call it, in Chrome, so that I can call a bookmark from the keyboard?

I have a bookmarklet that refreshes CSS without refreshing the page - pretty cool actually, if you're interested: http://david.dojotoolkit.org/recss.html.

Anyway, I use it often, and it would be nice to press `Ctrl + Command + R` or something to call it. Thoughts?

I've already seen [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/64242/access-google-chrome-bookmarks-with-keyboard-shortcuts), but I'm looking for a more direct "press this key combo to open bookmark 3" solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this extension:

> [Bookmarks Bar Keyboard Shortcuts](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/omgmmhpgegfcifjmhpenmjpignkegpal?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a Chrome extension that does this: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dnfpcpfijpdhabaoieccoclghgplmpbd

Comment: [CSS Reloader!!](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dnfpcpfijpdhabaoieccoclghgplmpbd)