# How can I return to a named anchor after scrolling in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, html, url

If I load a URL with a named anchor (like [this one](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmlenc-core-20021210/Overview.html#rsa-oaep-mgf1p)), Chrome takes me directly to the part of the page containing the anchor. So far, so good.

But if I scroll around a bit, I may lose track of where the anchor was. How can I return to the named anchor?

I tried refreshing the page, but Chrome doesn't take me back to the anchor. I've tried forced-refreshing (Ctrl-F5), to no effect. I've also tried Ctrl-L (to select the address bar) followed by ENTER to reload the page.

My workaround is to close the tab, then open a new one again with the full URL. This is quite annoying for someone who reads a lot of spec documents! Is there a better way?

Comment: Can't test Chrome, but on Safari refresh takes me back to exactly where I was, not to the anchor. Cmd/L [focus on URL bar] then Enter reloads the page at the anchor. It's a reload not a scroll, but it's fast enough.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sadly that doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: I dragged Chrome out to test… doesn't work on Mac either.

Comment: While the workaround solution is found (bookmarklet), is there a proper bug report for the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply execute some JavaScript to scroll the element to the top of the view:

```
document.getElementById(location.hash.slice(1)).scrollIntoView()
```

Source: [javascript - How to scroll HTML page to given anchor? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor)

For convenience, it's possible to add this as a bookmark on the bookmark bar, or [define a keyboard shortcut for it](https://superuser.com/questions/206760/google-chrome-attach-a-key-binding-to-a-bookmark).

```
javascript:document.getElementById(location.hash.slice(1)).scrollIntoView()
```

When there's no hash in the URL, it'll cause a (silent) JavaScript error. To scroll to the top of the page instead use

```
(document.getElementById(location.hash.slice(1))||document.body).scrollIntoView()
```

Answer (score 5):

**Use this bookmarklet:**

`javascript: var h = location.hash ; location.hash = "" ; location.hash = h ; null`

Explanation:

- Setting `location.hash` will cause the page to scroll to that anchor.
- As a special case, setting `location.hash` to *itself* is a no-op.
- It *does* scroll, however, if we set it to *something else* and then immediately back to the original value.
- Finally, bookmarklets must have `null`/`undefined` as their final value or (for historical reasons) they replace the page body with their final value.

---

**[The following is just for "extra credit"]**

Alternatively, we could do something along the lines of user202729’s answer.  His answer only works with anchors formed by `<a id="foo">`.  They don’t work with anchors that use `<a name="foo">`, e.g. those used here on SU/SO/SE!
We can catch those (possibly with false positives -- I didn't explore this approach so much) with

`javascript: var h = location.hash.slice(1) ; (document.getElementById(h) || document.getElementsByName(h)[0] || document.body).scrollIntoView()`

However even that approach fails on sites like github.com which use `<a class="anchor" href="#foo">`.  AFAICT, that approach is non-standard and requires custom javascript.  My initial approach above works on all three anchor styles.

p.s. I love the collaboration of ideas that can come from SE.  Reading user202729’s answer along with Dean Harding’s answer to [How to scroll HTML page to given anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3163635/577438) gave me the ideas I needed to experiment and noodle my way to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement solution by @Noach, I wanted to add info about how to create a bookmarklet. Bookmarklets are browser bookmarks that execute JavaScript instead of opening a webpage.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to create a bookmarklet link here in superuser.com, because of limitation of syntax. So you need add it manually.

To add a bookmarklet in Chromium, you can right-click your bookmarks bar, then click "Add page...".
Alternatively, you can go to your Bookmarks manager, then right-click and click "Add new bookmark":

In the "Name" field paste `re-anchor`. This text is what you will see in the bookmarks bar.
In the "URL" field paste `javascript: var h = location.hash ; location.hash = "" ; location.hash = h ; null`

[image]

Then place that newly created bookmarklet somewhere in the bar, so you can click it when needed.